# How do we test for infinite series convergence or divergence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

I am very new to MATLAB and still learning the ropes. I am looking for a generic method that tests a series for convergence or divergence for infinite series.

This is what I tried (I am using MATLAB online):

```
syms n
term = 1/n^.5;
y = vpa(symsum(term, n, 1, inf));
if isinf(y)
    fprintf('divergent\n');
else
    fprintf('convergent\n');
end
```

Answer: convergent

But this seems to give an incorrect answer! Can someone please explain how I can test for a generic series convergence in MATLAB using an inbuilt function? And if possible (when the series is convergent), print the sum of the infinite series?

Comment: I'm not sure you can reliably do this for all series. There is a reason why mathematicians are still relevant, computers can do finite numeric math well, but symbolic math, only good to a limit.

Comment: thanks. I understand. But for even simple series (for which the tests/results) are known, is there a known way to test. For eg: Above answers 'convergent', which I think is wrong. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with `symsum`. In fact, `vpa(symsum(term, n, 1, inf))` gives a finite, negative result (instead of the correct positive infinity) when `term` is defined with exponents between `0` and `1`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. So I stumbled on a bug with a first use of MATLAB! interesting. Can you please tell me if there is another way to test convergence of series (Reliably) in MATLAB using some predefined functions?

Comment: @stack.tarandeep I hope you don't get a bad impression of the language :-) Symbolic computations are not its strongest part. Still, it surprises me that it fails with something so basic. Consider [reporting the bug](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports)

Comment: For symbolic stuff [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/) is better. Do you have access to it?

Comment: I didn't get a bad impression but thought 'such bad luck!' :). I will report it in a bit. Sadly, I don't have access to Maple. I was thinking python has symbolic library: sympy but I am not sure if its that well developed (i.e. reliable).

Comment: I have never used Sympy directly (only via Octave's Symbolic package, which I think internally uses Sympy). But it seems to have [trouble](https://tio.run/##jY/BCoMwDIbvPkVgB1spDh3sMNjDVK0zqE3XVqFP39XJdpwLJH/4E/IRE/xA@hIjzoasBxdmE0C6rclGuG9apmxociwfc55thjEWtWf7cJln6ZE0q85jUdQCtmCjgEq8F4g4h1KtcuoZBw5wgpasVa2/gUFwz0Va1UGHK3ZJmwDXI0iqNRcHENRfjBtomTp44KqS3aNGH34z9i/@f@RzNcYX) with divergent series too

Comment: Just to add ... `vpa` is definitely not the right function to call here – especially if a series is divergent. The fact that `symsum` returns the summation expression itself tells you that it does not know how to show if this series is convergent or divergent. For other (simpler) series it can do this ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1909620-symsum-and-a-divergent-series)).

Comment: Have you tried the [Series Convergence Calculator](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72141-series-convergence-calculator) on the Mathworks File Exchange? You can also try [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2Fsqrt%28n%29+n%3D1+to+infinity).

Comment: @horchler I tried the Alpha link it works fine for small ones but for any substantial series, it states that "Standard Computaional Time Exceeded. Requires Pro Licence". and honestly I can't afford on right now. :( For eg: a series like this {$sum (1/(k+1)^.55)* (100.1*cos(100.1*log(k+1)) + (1-.55)*sin(100.1*log(k+1)))$ k=1 to infinity}, it throws this message.. i don't seem to find a reliable answer for this..

Comment: I tried this script [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72141-series-convergence-calculator] but I am not sure if this is correct for example for the series in above comment. I am very lost..